# How to add this html using c#

Tags: c#, html

I have a table in html,

```
<div id="top-body" class="p-body" style="height:800px; overflow:auto; display:block !important;">
    <table id="o-Table" class="myTable"></table>
</div>
```

Now I want to add this rows to it, but in page_load method, please guide,

```
  $("#o-Table").append(
            "<tr class='myRow'>" +
            "   <div class='myRow'>" +
            "       <td class='myCell'  onclick='DoSomething(\"" + someString + "\")'>" +
            "           <div class='myCell2'>" + someString2 + "</div>" +
            "       </td>" +
            "   </div>" +
            "</tr>");
```

Comment: I only need to figure out, how to dynamically add rows to table in C#, table will be already there

Comment: I'm not an expert here, but you need to know how to it in jQuery or C# (as title say)?

Answer (score 1):

You can create HTML elements in your code behind by using HtmlDocument.CreateElement, and then append it to your table with table.AppendChild.
More info can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.createelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

Example:

```
HtmlElement row = doc.CreateElement("TR");
table.AppendChild(row);
```

Another option is to use a gridview or listview.

Comment: what is doc, how to get table ? :S

Comment: The table should be the ID of your table element (o-Table).
Can't test now but perhaps you can create your row with System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRow row = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRow();

Answer (score 0):

When you tag `HTML` and `C#`, I'm gonna guess it's `ASP.NET`:

Add `<%= tableCode %>` inside the table to make room for a variable:

```
<div id="top-body" class="p-body" style="height:800px; overflow:auto; display:block !important;">
    <table id="o-Table" class="myTable">  <%= tableCode %>  </table>
</div>
```

Have a global variable declared in `C#` (global meaning outside any method):

```
public string tableCode;
```

and on `page_load`:

```
tableCode = "<tr class='myRow'>" +
            "   <div class='myRow'>" +
            "       <td class='myCell'  onclick='DoSomething(\"" + someString + "\")'>" +
            "           <div class='myCell2'>" + someString2 + "</div>" +
            "       </td>" +
            "   </div>" +
            "</tr>";
```

If it's not about `ASP.NET` please correct me, hope it helps ;)

Comment: it is asp.net, but as I described before, I have to add many rows dynamically

Comment: By dynamically do you mean with JavaScript?